# HTTPS is cancelled by Browser and my request is regarded as a HTTP request

Tags: javascript, http, web, github-pages

```
fetch('https://vanishingdante.github.io/gh-pages-blog-api/2017/02/11/bye-world')
  .then(resp => resp.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

I tried to fetch my json data from my gh-pages (gh-pages' `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is `*`)

By what I get is this:

[what code I use and what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHGmG.png)

and I checked the network panel in Chrome's devtool:

[network panel in Chrome's devtool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0fsL.png)

the https request is cancelled by browser, my fetch is regarded as a http request.

Why, and how to solve this

```
curl https://vanishingdante.github.io/gh-pages-blog-api/2017/02/11/bye-world -i
```

will get:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: GitHub.com
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://vanishingdante.github.io/gh-pages-blog-api/2017/02/11/bye-world/
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Expires: Mon, 20 Feb 2017 07:08:43 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=600
X-GitHub-Request-Id: F932:2F9ED:6B263C9:9012708:58AA93A3
Content-Length: 178
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2017 06:58:43 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-nrt6121-NRT
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1487573923.394396,VS0,VE179
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Fastly-Request-ID: 7acb3e168a104bffe672ee2c77215cd750197a3f

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

request to https will be redirect to http

```
curl http://vanishingdante.github.io/gh-pages-blog-api/2017/02/11/bye-world -i
```

will get:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: GitHub.com
Content-Type: text/html
Location: https://vanishingdante.github.io/gh-pages-blog-api/2017/02/11/bye-world
X-GitHub-Request-Id: C9E0:786B:3CE9A28:5028A16:58AA941A
Content-Length: 178
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2017 07:00:43 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Age: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-nrt6122-NRT
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1487574043.118608,VS0,VE179
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Fastly-Request-ID: d4377ad8a08c54c1328558908b91941739f27279

<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

and http request will be redirected to https

Answer (score 1):

A request to `https://vanishingdante.github.io/gh-pages-blog-api/2017/02/11/bye-world` generates a 301 (*"Moved Permanently"*) to `http://vanishingdante.github.io/gh-pages-blog-api/2017/02/11/bye-world/`, which is causing your problems.

In [this blog post](https://github.com/blog/2186-https-for-github-pages) it's noted that if your site already existed before June 15th 2016, you need to enable HTTPS support manually in the settings for the site.

Comment: But my site was created 9 days ago, and the HTTPS enforce is on